# How to change the Menu configuration of laravel AdminLTE, other than the menu Icons (like the links). I need to update the logo on runtime based on DB

Tags: laravel, adminlte

I need to Update the Logo on the Laravel AdminLTE on runtime based on a value from Database, as currently it is handled by the adminlte.php config file.
I have tried passing a global variable (say $logoUrl) to every view with View Composers and then I use javascript to change the logo src value.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('brand-image')[0].src = "{{ $logoUrl}}"
})
```

This works but it takes a split second to reflect after the page loads.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: I think it would be quicker if you added some PHP in your blade file to update the logo since you have the new logo URL available as a var in PHP anyway. No need for JS in this issue unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yes .. that would have been possible with regular php/laravel's blade, but the way Laravel AdminLTE works is that it has a config file (with static values to pass, like logo_url=/public/images/logo.png etc). So I can't pass variables to that config file which renders the sidebar menu.

Comment: Are you using this package? https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this package https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Views-Customization.

Then you're able to publish the views if you need to customise them by running this command:
`php artisan adminlte:install --only=main_views`

[Here you can read about customising the views.](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Views-Customization)

Comment: Yes .. looks like the way to go. Will try it .. thanks for helping out.